# Can I use ksdiff over ssh?

Tags: git, ssh, diff, git-diff, kaleidoscope

I've configured my `.gitconfig` using Kakeidoscope's integration tool. This basically installs `ksdiff`, adds it to bash enviroment and updates `.gitconfig` to use `ksdiff` as `difftool` and `mergetool`.

All this works fine until I ssh my remote box. That enviroment of course does not have `ksdiff` installed so it doesn't work.

I've tried copying the gitconf settings to remote.

But that alone still doesnt do the trick:

```
[mergetool "Kaleidoscope"]
        cmd = ksdiff --merge --output \"$MERGED\" --base \"$BASE\" -- \"$LOCAL\" --snapshot \"$REMOTE\" --snapshot
        trustexitcode = true
[merge]
        tool = Kaleidoscope
[difftool "Kaleidoscope"]
        cmd = ksdiff --partial-changeset --relative-path \"$MERGED\" -- \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
[difftool]
        prompt = false
[mergetool]
        prompt = false
[diff]
        tool = Kaleidoscope
```

So my question is: Is it possible to make my remote ssh enviroment run `ksdiff` locally (launching local GUI diff tool)?

Comment: Why not simply clone to your local machine where you have all your tools available? If you can access a git repository via SSH, you can clone it.

Comment: I rly wish this was possible.. our dev environments are not configured to run locally at the moment.. we're working on moving to local vagrant boxes.. but at the moment ssh is the only way. :(

Comment: That's a bummer. But you could still do merges on your local box (provided git is installed) with your graphical tools and do everything else remotely. I haven't tried but it shouldn't be too hard to set up.